¿Por qué y donde se esta generando un problema de ambito? c#
Estoy realizando un programa en c# sobre un tablero de ajedrez. Mi problema es que cuando creo y le asigno una posición a la pieza y a la dama en el tablero que es una matriz tipo pieza de 8x8 por alguna razon no esta guardando los datos en la matriz originalmente creada y al momento de querer imprimirla la imprime vacia, pero si la imprimo desde las mismas funciones de asignarPieza si las imprime con las piezas asignadas. Estuve revisando y parece ser un problema de ambito entre los metodos, pero no entiendo debido a que se esta generando porque antes funcionaba correctamente, intente quitar el ciclo while en los metodos de asignar posición que su función es validar cuando se quiere utilizar una casilla ya disponible, pero aun quitando el ciclo while sigue persistiendo el problema.
public class Tablero
{


   public Piezas[,] piezasTab = new Piezas[8, 8];


   //Metodo para asginarle una posición a una pieza creada.
   public void AsignarPosición(Piezas pieza)
   {

      int X = 0;
      Console.WriteLine("Ingrese la posición ");
      string posi = Console.ReadLine();

      //Se realiza un bucle en la asignación para poder validar las posiciones.
      while (X == 0)
      {
         string cl = posi[0].ToString();
         char fl = posi[1];

         int col = 0;
         int fil = 0;

         //Transformación de la notación de matriz a notación de tablero.
         switch (cl)
         {
            case "a":
               col = 0;
               break;
            case "b":
               col = 1;
               break;
            case "c":
               col = 2;
               break;
            case "d":
               col = 3;
               break;
            case "e":
               col = 4;
               break;
            case "f":
               col = 5;
               break;
            case "g":
               col = 6;
               break;
            case "h":
               col = 7;
               break;
         }

         switch (fl)
         {
            case '1':
               fil = 7;
               break;
            case '2':
               fil = 6;
               break;
            case '3':
               fil = 5;
               break;
            case '4':
               fil = 4;
               break;
            case '5':
               fil = 3;
               break;
            case '6':
               fil = 2;
               break;
            case '7':
               fil = 1;
               break;
            case '8':
               fil = 0;
               break;
         }
         //Validación de que la posición deseada este disponible en el tablero.

         if (piezasTab[fil, col] != null)
         {
            Console.WriteLine("Posición no disponible");
            Console.WriteLine(piezasTab[fil, col].Tipo);
            Console.WriteLine("Ingrese una posición valida");
            posi = Console.ReadLine();
         }
         else
         {

            Console.WriteLine("");
            try
            { //try catch utilizado para verificar si hay algun error al momento de guardar el objeto en la posición.
               piezasTab[fil, col] = pieza;
               Console.WriteLine($"Pieza agregada exitosamente: {piezasTab[fil, col].Tipo}");
               Console.WriteLine($"Coordenada Tablero [{fil},{col}], {posi}");
            }
            catch (ArgumentException e)
            {
               Console.WriteLine(e.Message);
            }
            X = 1;
         }
      }

      //impresion
      Console.WriteLine("Impresión de matriz interna de la función asignarPieza");
      for (int i = 0; i < piezasTab.GetLength(0); i++) //fila
      {
         for (int j = 0; j < piezasTab.GetLength(1); j++) //columna
         {
            if (piezasTab[i, j] == null)
            {
               Console.Write(" - ");
            }
            else
            {
               Console.Write($"{piezasTab[i, j].Tipo[0]}.{piezasTab[i, j].Color}");
            }
         }
         Console.WriteLine();
      }
   }

   public void AsignarPosición(Dama dama)
   {
      int X = 0;
      Console.WriteLine("Ingrese la posición ");
      string posi = Console.ReadLine();

      while (X == 0)
      {
         string cl = posi[0].ToString();
         char fl = posi[1];


         int col = 0;
         int fil = 0;
         //Transformación de la notación de matriz a notación de tablero.
         switch (cl)
         {
            case "a":
               col = 0;
               break;
            case "b":
               col = 1;
               break;
            case "c":
               col = 2;
               break;
            case "d":
               col = 3;
               break;
            case "e":
               col = 4;
               break;
            case "f":
               col = 5;
               break;
            case "g":
               col = 6;
               break;
            case "h":
               col = 7;
               break;
         }

         switch (fl)
         {
            case '1':
               fil = 7;
               break;
            case '2':
               fil = 6;
               break;
            case '3':
               fil = 5;
               break;
            case '4':
               fil = 4;
               break;
            case '5':
               fil = 3;
               break;
            case '6':
               fil = 2;
               break;
            case '7':
               fil = 1;
               break;
            case '8':
               fil = 0;
               break;
         }
         //Validación de que la posición deseada este disponible en el tablero.
         if (piezasTab[fil, col] != null)
         {
            Console.WriteLine("Posición no disponible");
            Console.WriteLine();
            Console.WriteLine("Ingrese una posición valida");
            posi = Console.ReadLine();

         }
         else
         {

            Console.WriteLine("");
            piezasTab[fil, col] = dama;
            Console.WriteLine("Dama agregada exitosamente");
            X = 1;
         }
      }
      //impresión
       Console.WriteLine("Impresión de matriz interna de la función asignarDama");
      for (int i = 0; i < piezasTab.GetLength(0); i++) //fila
      {
         for (int j = 0; j < piezasTab.GetLength(1); j++) //columna
         {
            if (piezasTab[i, j] == null)
            {
               Console.Write(" - ");
            }
            else
            {
               Console.Write($"{piezasTab[i, j].Tipo[0]}.{piezasTab[i, j].Color}");
            }
         }
         Console.WriteLine();
      }
   }

   //Metodo para imprimir la matriz
   public void ImprimirMatriz(ref Piezas[,] piezasTab)
   {
      for (int i = 0; i < piezasTab.GetLength(0); i++) //fila
      {
         for (int j = 0; j < piezasTab.GetLength(1); j++) //columna
         {
            if (piezasTab[i, j] == null)
            {
               Console.Write(" - ");
            }
            else
            {
               Console.Write($"{piezasTab[i, j].Tipo[0]}.{piezasTab[i, j].Color}");
            }
         }
         Console.WriteLine();
      }
   }


¿Por qué pasas el arreglo piezasTab como parámetro al método ImprimirMatriz, que pretenece a Tablero y que ya tiene declarado su propio miembro piezasTab? Un tablero no va a imprimir el arreglo de otro, ¿o sí?. Por otro lado, ¿por qué pasas este parámetro por referencia?
